# Vim new tabbed pages don't match text

Tags: tabs, match, vim, highlight

I use `:match` to highlight problems with my code that don't meet style guidelines. The following works great for the first window I open in Vim:

**`~/.vimrc`:**

```
hi ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
hi NoFunctionSpace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
2match NoFunctionSpace /\S(/
```

However, when I go to `:tabedit` a file, or if I open Vim with the `-p` option and multiple files, only the first window highlights matches. I want all of my open tabs to show matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:match` commands only apply to the current window. To automatically apply them to each new window, hook them into the `WinEnter` event:

```
autocmd WinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
autocmd WinEnter * 2match NoFunctionSpace /\S(/
```

You still need the original `:match` commands, too, because the `WinEnter` event isn't fired for the initial window.

Comment: I discovered that if I use BufEnter instead of WinEnter I can remove the original `:match`. I also use `call matchadd` instead of `:match` because then I can call it as many times as I want. So result: `autocmd BufEnter * call matchadd("WhitespaceEOL", '\s\+$')`

Comment: `matchadd()` is good; so you can still have `:match` left for interactive use. But `BufEnter` is wrong; as both are scoped to the window. You may notice it not working when splitting the current buffer with `:split`.